# How can i make password encryption in which there should be no special characters just alpha-numeric characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

How can i make password encryption in which there should be no special characters just alpha-numeric characters. 
I am using asp.net application in which i have made encrypted URLs so whenever a special characters come in URL it breaks that URL when i am posting some where.
Like in right align input fields it always gets disturb, so i need to resolve it and make encrypted password in which there should be no such special character that break URL.

Comment: you shouldn't be limiting passwords based on their compatibility with urls.  Have you considered using a GUID or similar mechanism to transfer between secure pages?

Comment: thanks for you comment..there is something implemented in this application and i have to replace this algorithm so that my algorithm will generate such strings that will not break URLs....any idea how this will be generated?

Comment: One option is to store user information (except the password) in session, and pass that info between pages. ASP Session State Overview: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581(v=vs.100).aspx"

Comment: i know about session handling but it would be too much work because application is already made and I found the one way that will take less time than others and its to change the way of encryption decryption, currently algorithm works fine but the only issue is that it also creates symbols like $ and = as well and i don't know how to limit that because that is built in asp.net encryption method.

Comment: I would look into replacing your algorithm with akton's suggestion then

Comment: it will be much work to do because its not 10 to 20 pages application thats why, and i need to encrypt not only passwords but query string parameters as well. what would you say for this if i do not want to use session for this..

Comment: i found this way but its not yet fully verified. now i am testing that it would work for me or not. thanks all of you. http://dotnetaid.com/2011/08/01/how-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-string-in-c-net/

Answer (score 6):

Encrypt or hash the password as normal then use [HttpUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode.aspx) or [WebUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility.urlencode.aspx) to get a URL friendly version.

Comment: thanks for you comment..there is something implemented in this application and i have to replace this algorithm so that my algorithm will generate such strings that will not break URLs....any idea how this will be generated? I just need to encrypt and decrypt passwords or ids of users so that i can manage the application....

Comment: i found this way but its not yet fully verified. http://dotnetaid.com/2011/08/01/how-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-string-in-c-net/

Comment: @AqEel I would avoid the algorithm in the link (Base 64 encoding). If you want to develop a secure application, you have to assume attackers know the system (called Shannon's Maxim). Any keyless password protection can be circumvented much more easily and a keyed one. I realise cryptography is complicated but it is worth the investment if you want the application to be secure.